# Check Installer Permissions with Windows Visual Studio 2008 C#

Tags: winforms, installation, uac

Lots of Installer questions, but I can't find the answer to what I want.

I've got an installer that can log in an Administrator account to continue the setup, but I don't know how to check the current user to see if he/she already has Administrator or Power User privileges.

How can I check to see what kind of permissions the current user has before calling my Administrator login form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can already put in the installer the command `runas`, read more at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control#Requesting_elevation) - Remember that this command will make the person need to use the administrator privileges.

For Windows XP I suggest you to read:

- [Microsoft Windows XP Runas](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/runas.mspx?mfr=true)
- [In Windows, how can I run an administrator task from a non-admin account?](http://kb.iu.edu/data/augx.html)
- [HOW TO: Use the RUN AS Command to Start a Program as an Administrator in Windows XP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/305780)

Comment: Is this only available for Vista and up or can XP use it, too? 90% of our computers at this company are XP.